# Precision in String

Tags: java, string, double, decimal

I have the following code:

```
 String price="9000.89";
        double basePrice =10000;

        String dis= String.valueOf(((basePrice - Double
                .parseDouble(price)) * 100 / basePrice));
 System.out.println(dis);
```

It is giving me the output as "9.991100000000007", but i need it in 2 decimal points. Any idea how to do that?

Expected output : 9.99

Comment: Why does it have to be stored as a string and not a double?

Comment: Datatype cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
String price="9000.89";
double basePrice =10000; 
String dis = String.format("%.2f",((basePrice - Double.parseDouble(price)) * 100 / basePrice)); 
System.out.println(dis);
```

Comment: It is giving Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Comment: ` String price="9000.89";
        double basePrice =10000;
        double dis = ((basePrice - Double.parseDouble(price)) * 100 / basePrice);
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", dis));`

Comment: I cannot change the Datatype of dis from String to double

Comment: String price="9000.89";
        double basePrice =10000;
        String dis = String.format("%.2f",((basePrice - Double.parseDouble(price)) * 100 / basePrice));
        System.out.println(dis);

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend

```
double dis = ((basePrice - Double.parseDouble(price)) * 100 / basePrice);
System.out.format("%1.2f", dis);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can round using:

```
Math.round(number * 100.0) / 100.0;
```